# Use line wrap in JTextArea that wraps the line to a specific position in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, chat, jtextarea, messenger

I have a `JTextArea` that picks up text from another `JTextArea` and displays that text as seen in this image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOEdR.png]

I want the JTextArea to wrap the line from where rahul  is written as in previous image.
And below is the code from my smaller `JTextArea` from which the text is shown in the larger `JTextArea`.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    String str=MainFrame.un+" ("+sdf.format(new Date())+")  :"+txtSend.getText();

    DataServices.send(runm+":"+str); // for sending this to its socket

    txtView.append("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t"+str);
    txtSend.setText("");
    txtSend.requestFocus(true);
```

Comment: The text will wrap when the text reaches the right edge of the text area. This will happen automatically when wrapping is turned on. Otherwise, the text will be moved to a new line when the newline character is found. So if you want to force a new line then you need to manually add the newline character.

Comment: yea exactly @camickr but i want it to start from where rahul is written just below that not from left edge of text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want it to start from where rahul is written just below that not from left edge of text area

This is not supported in a JTextArea. A JTextArea is used for displaying simple text.

You could use a JTextPane. It allows you to control attributes of the text and one of the attributes could be the left indent. So you can set the paragraph attributes for a single line to be indented by a specific number of pixels.

So instead of using tabs to indent the text you would just need to set the left indent when you add the line of text.

Note also that a JTextPane does not implement an append method so you would need to create your own by adding text directly to the Document using:

```
textPane.getDocument.insertString(...);
```

So the basic logic would be:

```
StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument();
doc.insertString(...);
SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
//StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(attrs, 50);
StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(attrs, 50);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength(),attrs, false);
```

This will change the indent of the line of text you just added to the text pane.