# JTable not able to set header background color

Tags: java, swing, background, header, jtable

Created a table to show reports, everything else is working but I am not able to set the header background color. I have tried changing the `setOpaque()` and another thing I would like to avoid using custom renderer for the problem.

My code for creating the table is as follows.

```
private void showTable() {
    if (alUserRecord != null) {
        String heading[] = {"Username", "Groupname", "Groupstatus"};
        String data[][] = new String[alUserRecord.size()][heading.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < alUserRecord.size(); i++) {
            GroupManageBean objbean = alUserRecord.get(i);
            data[i][0] = objbean.getUsername();
            data[i][1] = objbean.getGroupname();
            if (objbean.isGroupstatus()) {
                data[i][2] = "Active";
            } else {
                data[i][2] = "Inactive";
            }
        }
        tblUserReport = new JTable(data, heading);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblUserReport);
        tblUserReport.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        tblUserReport.setBackground(new Color(161,158,152));
        tblUserReport.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,102,102), 2, true));
        tblUserReport.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,102,102));
        tblUserReport.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

In the above code `alUserRecord` is an `ArrayList` that gets its values from another method that fetches the data from MySQL database. By the way every line in this code is working except `tblUserReport.getTableHeader().setBackground.....`.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: `Can anyone please help me with that?` - I could but I've helped you with a couple of questions in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796676/render-icon-to-the-right-side-in-the-jlist-using-defaultlistcellrenderer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559116/use-line-wrap-in-jtextarea-that-wraps-the-line-to-a-specific-position-in-jtextar and you have never replied with a thank you and you have never accepted any answer to any of your questions, so I think I'll skip this one.

Comment: @camickr I am sorry actually I am new to this stack overflow thing and that's the only reason.  I have noticed that you replied previously to my questions and thank you so much for that. I just didn't know I can show that thanks back to you

Comment: `I am sorry actually I am new to this stack overflow thing and that's the only reason.` - "accepting" answer is a stack overflow concept, but saying thank you is universal. You should be replying to all suggestions indicating whether they helped or not. Anyway I can't answer you question because it is not complete. Maybe the problem is your LAF. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. A `MCVE` should be posted with each question.